# python matplotlib how to get multiple axes handles

Tags: python, matplotlib

My plot contains many subplots and I need a list of handles to treat each one of them. Right now I do the following

```
axes = [fig.add_subplot(2,3,1), fig.add_subplot(2,3,2),                       
        fig.add_subplot(2,3,3), fig.add_subplot(2,3,4),                       
        fig.add_subplot(2,3,5), fig.add_subplot(2,3,6)]
```

Is there a built-in function to get `axes` more succinctly by simply specifying 2, and 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
f, ((ax1, ax2, ax3),(ax4, ax5, ax6)) = plt.subplots(2, 3)
```

or:

```
f, axarray = plt.subplots(2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use list comprehensions:

```
axes = [fig.add_subplot(2,3,i+1) for i in range(6)]
```

Or a little generally:

```
x = 2
y = 3
axes = [fig.add_subplot(x,y,i+1) for i in range(x*y)]
```